# 4th order linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While I was solving an integral using Feynman Integration, I came across the following differential equation:

$$y’’’’-y’’+y=0$$

I tried substituting $y$ with an exponential function which failed. Can someone else show me how to solve it?

Comment: what are the roots of $\lambda^4 - \lambda^2 + 1  \; ? \; \; $

Comment: That’s where i got. My issue with that was they were complex. If you want to solve for the roots of the quartic, start with substituting for  squared and use the quadratic formula. @WillJagy

Comment: if $s,t$ are real and $i$  is the usual  complex number  with $i^2 = -1,$   what is $e^{s+it}  \; ? \; \; \; $

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I only started teaching myself differential equations very recently so this was very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$λ^4−λ^2+1$$ can be completed to a square by variation of the middle term, making it more negative in the process
$$=(λ^2+1)^2−3λ^2=(λ^2+\sqrt3λ+1)(λ^2-\sqrt3λ+1)$$
Now one can apply the usual solution formulas for quadratic equations (with real coefficients but complex roots).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The characteristic equation of you ODE is $x^4-x^2+1=0$ which, when multiplied in $x^2+1$, yields $x^6+1=0$. Hence, the roots of $x^4-x^2+1$ are those of $x^6=-1$ except those of $x^2=-1$.